# Open POPUP window in Outlook web addin from Command button

Tags: outlook-addin

I am trying to open a small popup window from Command button in Outlook web addin . Below is the method 
(function () {

```
// The initialize function must be run each time a new page is loaded
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ShowPopup();
    });
};

 function loadItemProps(item) {
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://myAddinDomain/myDialog.html');

}
```

But it is not working , no error .

Comment: Take the ShowPopup() out of the initialize function.

Comment: And add it where? Also, what does it do? Rohit, did you ever get this to work? If so, please post an answer and accept it, to help others.