# OWA Addin code written gives a pane within the mail, but i need it to pop a window and display the webpage in default browser

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

```
FormSettings>


Form xsi:type="ItemRead">


DesktopSettings>

SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://www.google.com"/>

RequestedWidth>800/RequestedWidth>

RequestedHeight>800/RequestedHeight>

/DesktopSettings>

/Form>

/FormSettings>
```

what has to be used in order to get a pop up browser on clicking that hyperlink

Comment: Did you checked this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49860113/open-popup-window-in-outlook-web-addin-from-command-button  

You could try take the ShowPopup() out of the initialize function.

Answer (score 1):

If you also want the task pane to open, you can start with an add-in command that only executes a JavaScript function. See [an overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/add-in-commands-for-outlook#executing-a-javascript-function) and [an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-addin-commands#step-5-add-the-functionfile-element).

Then either call the [displayDialogAsync API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) to open a window that can communicate with the add-in (the kind of window depends on the client), or call [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) to open an external web page in the default browser.

When the add-in's JavaScript has finished executing, remember to call event.completed() per the first example to stop the add-in.